# Как переключаться между страницами wpf

Tags: wpf

Я делаю игру, и у меня есть страница меню и страница с самой игрой. Скажите, пожалуйста, как между ними переключаться? На странице с меню есть кнопка, при помощи которой можно перейти на страницу игры.

Какая вообще в принципе должна быть логика в таких приложениях?

Comment: [Navigation with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: Определите свои ContentControl для меню и для игры и просто меняйте свойство Content окна

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, видимо, такой.

1. Вы пишете с MVVM? Заведите себе по VM-классу для меню и всех страниц игры.
2. Заведите в главной VM свойство `ActivePage`, в начале присвойте ему экземпляр `MenuVM`, для переключения на первую страницу присвойте экземпляр `Page1VM` и т. д. Не забудьте правильно реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
3. Страницы превратите в `UserControl`'ы.
4. Положите в `App.xaml` шаблоны, привязывающие VM к `UserControl`'ам:

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MenuVM}">
           <view:MenuControl/>
       </DataTemplate>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstPageVM}">
           <view:FirstPageControl/>
       </DataTemplate>
       <!-- и так далее -->
   </Application.Resources>
   ```
5. В `MainWindow.xaml` положите код, который будет выбирать нужный шаблон в зависимости от типа `ActivePage`:

   ```
   <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ActivePage}"/>
   ```

Таким образом, логика перехода между страницами уходит в VM-уровень. А там переключение сводится просто к присвоению переменной значения.

Всё!

Answer (score 0):

Вместо страниц используйте [Prism](https://habrahabr.ru/post/176851/). Там навигация проще и ещё есть куча плюсов по управлению жизни объектов