# Переход со страницы на страницу в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Этот вопрос является логическим продолжеием [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801159/wpf-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9) вопроса.
Я попытался реализовать схему, изложенную [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740492/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-wpf/740529#740529) , но программа не работает.
Я опишу свои шаги по реализации схемы по второй ссылке, и буду цитировать шаги оттуда со своим кодом. Цитаты  выделены курсивом.

*Положите в `App.xaml` шаблоны, привязывающие VM к `UserControl`'ам*:

```
<Application x:Class="PresentationLayer.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PresentationLayer"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PresentationLayer.WPFViewModels"
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:PresentationLayer.Views"
         StartupUri="StartWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StartPageVM}">
        <view:StartPage/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FLPPage1VM}">
        <view:FLPPage1></view:FLPPage1>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
Заведите в главной VM свойство `ActivePage`, в начале присвойте ему экземпляр `StartPageVM`...

 public  class MainVM : BaseVM
{
    public static BaseVM ActivePage { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        ActivePage = new StartPageVM();
    }
}
```

Здесь все работает. При запуске программы меня автоматически перебрасывает на `StartPage` с таким кодом:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PresentationLayer.Views.StartPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PresentationLayer.Views"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PresentationLayer.WPFViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="500">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:StartPageVM></vm:StartPageVM>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" Foreground="DarkGreen" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding FLPStartCommand}">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Регистрационные действия  ФЛП</TextBlock>
    </Button>

    <Button Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="16" Foreground="DarkGreen" FontWeight="Bold" IsEnabled="False" Command="{Binding SettingsCommand}">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Настройки </TextBlock>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Соответствующая VM

```
 public class StartPageVM : BaseVM
{
   public BaseVM ActivePage { get; set; }
    public ICommand FLPStartCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand SettingsCommand { get; set; }

    public StartPageVM()
    {
        FLPStartCommand = new RelayCommand(x => FLPStartMethod());
        SettingsCommand = new RelayCommand(x => SettingsMethod());


    }

    private void FLPStartMethod()
    {
        MainVM.ActivePage = new FLPPage1VM();
        //OnPropertyChanged("PresentationLayer.WPFViewModels.MainVM.ActivePage");


    }

    private void SettingsMethod()
    {

    }

}
```

*для переключения на первую страницу присвойте экземпляр `FLPPage1VM` и т. д*
Я ожидаю, что  при нажатии на кнопку меня перебросит на страницу `FLPPage1`. Однако, программа на нажатbе кнопки не реагирует. Что я сделал не так? Если раскомментировать вызов `OnPropertyChanged` ничего не меняется.

Код `FLPPage1` и `FLPPage1VM`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PresentationLayer.Views.FLPPage1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PresentationLayer.Views"
         xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:PresentationLayer.WPFViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:FLPPage1VM></vm:FLPPage1VM>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid Background="Aquamarine">
    <TextBlock>PAGE FLP1</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

VM пустая пока, но приведу для полноты картины:

```
 public  class FLPPage1VM: BaseVM
{
    FLPCompleteEntity FLP { get; set; }
}
```

Для справки:
Класс `VMBase` Брал с предыдущего проекта, должен быть рабочий:

```
public class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Класс `RelayCommand` (тоже с предыдущего проекта)

```
public class RelayCommand:ICommand
{
    public Predicate<object> CanExecuteDelegate { get; set; }
    public Action<object> ExecuteDelegate { get; set; }


    public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        ExecuteDelegate = action;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecuteDelegate != null)
        {
            return CanExecuteDelegate(parameter);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (ExecuteDelegate != null)
        {
            ExecuteDelegate(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ого, большой вопрос. Сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас неверно реализован интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Вы должны отправлять `NotifyPropertyChanged`, а имя свойства не должно содержать «пути» к свойству. Причём отправлять `NotifyPropertyChanged` должен *именно тот* объект, в котором меняется свойство. А также, это самое свойство не должно быть статическим.

Я бы посоветовал реализовать это так:

```
// https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632894/10105
class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value,
                         [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

```
public class MainVM : BaseVM
{
    BaseVM activePage;
    public BaseVM ActivePage
    {
        get => activePage;
        set => Set(ref activePage, value);
    }

    public MainVM()
    {
        ActivePage = new StartPageVM();
    }
}
```

При этом нужное имя отправляется в событие `PropertyChanged` автоматически (посредством «волшебного» атрибута `CallerMemberName`).

---

Следующая ошибка — задание `DataContext` внутри контрола. Это неправильно. Во-первых, вы уже и так задаёте `DataContext` снаружи, а значит, внешний `DataContext` будет проигнорирован, хотя как раз он у вас правильно связан с другими VM. А во-вторых, с точки зрения MVVM у View нет прав определять свой `DataContext`.

Просто уберите

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    ...
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

из кода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 2 вопроса: 1. Если переписать ActivePage из C#7  в более раннюю версию, там будут какие-то особенности или обычное свойство. только с ref?  2. как мне из StartPageVM изменить ActivePage? Нужно экземпляр MainVM передавать дальше во все VM?

Comment: @foxhound: Ну будет `get { return activePage; }` и т. п., а так никаких особенных изменений.

Comment: @foxhound: Это вам как автору программы решать, как связать между собой два объекта. Например, вы можете скормить классу `StartPageVM` в конструкторе ваш экземпляр `MainVM`.

Comment: Понятно что мне. Я о принципе. Насколько я понял Ваши исправления ответа,   для открытия любого окна в программе , 
 мне будет нужен именно тот, первичный экземпляр MainVM, в котром было создано свойство ActivePage. Так?

Comment: @foxhound: Именно так. Вы строите дерево VM-объектов, и привязываете к нему View. Соответственно View не должно создавать VM-объекты само. Ну и корневой VM-объект должен быть только один.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вроде как заработало

Comment: @foxhound: Вот и отлично! Пожалуйста!