# Привязка событий к командам WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня в окне - динамический список, который я реализую через `ItemsControl` 
Мне нужно обработать события, происходящие в `TextBox`  в этом списке. Если более точно, то сделать автодобавление символа после ввода первых двух и автозаполнение `TextBlock` в момент потери фокуса.
Попытался реализовать через `EventTrigger`, как советовали на англоязычном StackOverflow. Ошибок нет, но отладчик на команды не заходит. Программа их просто не видит.
Кнопка работает, строки в список добавляются, но команды не привязываются
Что я делаю не так и как мне правильно обработать события в динамическом контроле?

Код:
XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="PresentationLayer.Views.FLPStream.StartFlp03"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PresentationLayer.Views.FLPStream"
         xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:BusinessLayer.ViewModels.VM.SecondaryEntitiesVM;assembly=BusinessLayer"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="900">

<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="5"
        Text="Окно добавления видов деятлеьности. Нажмите кнопку Добавить для добавления вида деятельности. Количество видов ограничено 21"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    </TextBlock>
    <Button 
        Grid.Row="1"
        Content="Добавить вид деятельности"
        Width="250"
        Height="auto"
        FontFamily="Arial"
        FontSize="16"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Padding="10"
        Foreground="DarkGreen"
        Margin="10"
        Command="{Binding AddActivityCommand}"
        />

    <ScrollViewer
        Grid.Row="2"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox 
                            Name="code"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Width="50"
                            Text="{Binding ActivityCode}"
                            Margin="50,10">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeTextCommand}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ActivityCode}" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </TextBox>
                        <StackPanel 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="20,10">
                            <TextBlock 
                               Name="actName"
                                Text="{Binding ActivityName}"/>
                            <TextBlock  
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Name="ErrMessage"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button MinWidth="100" Margin="40,0,40,0" Command="{Binding BackCommand}">
            <TextBlock Text="Назад" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
        </Button>
        <Button MinWidth="100" Margin="40,0,40,0" IsEnabled="{Binding RadiobuttonIsSelected}" Command="{Binding ForwardCommand}" >
            <TextBlock Text="Дальше" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Margin="10" ></TextBlock>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

VM (часть):

```
    public RelayCommand ForwardCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand BackCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand AddActivityCommand { get; set;}
    public RelayCommand ChangeTextCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand LostFocusCommand { get; set; }



    public StartFLPVM3(MainVM mainPage)
    {
        BackCommand = new RelayCommand(x => BackMethod());
        ForwardCommand = new RelayCommand(x => ForwardMethod());
        ChangeTextCommand = new RelayCommand(x => ChangeTextMethod());
        AddActivityCommand = new RelayCommand(x => AddActivityMethod());
        LostFocusCommand = new RelayCommand(delegate (object s) { LostFocusMethod(s);});
        Activities = new ObservableCollection<ActivityVM> ();
    }


    private void AddActivityMethod()
    {
        var activity = new ActivityVM();
        Activities.Add (activity);
    }

    private void ChangeTextMethod()
    {
        //if(text.Length ==2)
        //{
        //    text += ".";
        //}
    }
    private void LostFocusMethod(object code)
    {

    }
```

Реализацию класса `RelayCommand` при необходимости можно взять здесь: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803527/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2-wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хватает кода ActivityVM для уверенного суждения, но, судя по приведённому коду, вы надеетесь на то, что команда, назначенная основной VM, будет работать для объекта, являющегося элементом его свойства-коллекции.

Проще говоря, вам надо перенести  ChangeTextCommand и LostFocusCommand в ActivityVM.

Comment: ActivityVM - это модель, очищенная от служебных полей базы данных. Только свойства и конструктор. Она вообще в BusinessLogic Layer.