# Как объединить несколько окон в однои окне С# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, usercontrol

У меня есть проект на WPF С#, а точнее заготовки для приложения такие как регистрация, авторизация и основной контент у виде файлов з форматом .xaml. Например, Logining.xaml, Main.xaml и т. д. Как мне сделать так что-бы при запуске приложения показывалось контент з авторизацией (Logining.xaml), и если авторизация успешно завершена, тогда переходим к окну из главным контентом (Main.xaml), но в том же окне, а контент из авторизацией пропадает. То есть есть одно окно, и все действия делаем в этом окне

Comment: Вам надо реализовать нечто [подобное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543348/222542)

Comment: Вот дубликаты: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/763691/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/740492/10105. В первом примере так вообще именно авторизация и упоминается.

Comment: @VladD использовал ваши рекомендации, не понял как я могу перемещаться од одного usercontrol к другому, при етом передавая данные. Например: usercontrol Logining.xaml мне нужно передать логин и пароль, я их ввожу у поля, и нажимаю кнопку что-бы отправить, но здесь загвоздка, usercontrol не позволяет оброблять события, например Click

Comment: @VLAD: Данными пусть обмениваются прикреплённые VM, как в примере https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/10105. А у кнопки есть событие Click, посмотрите, должно быть доступно и в UserControl'е.

Comment: @VladD  Он есть, когда я запускаю приложения, то мне показывает что UserControl не содержит определение Button_Click или отсутствует ссылка на зборку. Хотя все подключено, сам пробовал по другому подключать, но результата никакого. Это я пишу об связи фала .xaml и класа для роботи з ним .cs

Comment: @VLAD: Мне сложно что-то подсказать наугад. Покажите ваш код. Возможно, стоит отредактировать вопрос.

Comment: @VLAD проблему решил, осталось только сформирировать один ViewModel для роботи з контентами